# How to embed SendGrid API into Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, sendgrid

I want to use SendGrid to send emails, in my Symfony 2 project.

(Reason why I use SendGrid is because I used it very easily before. All that is needed is to unzip the PHP files that comprise the SendGrid API and include two files from it, and you can use the SendGrid object to send emails)

Now, what is the best way to do this, from inside Symfony? Do I need to make a separate bundle with SendGrid API in it? Is this a good way to do it? -Since I read on Symfony website that 3rd party API-s should not be embedded as a bundle. But, how to use them then?

Edit: I have found out that swift mailer should work good with SendGrid, so I tried setting the parameters.yml to the sendgrid parameters. I sent the message through the Symfony, now using Swift Message, but I can't see the email, and also I can see that my SendGrid server has not even been reached at all. What is needed to set the parameters so that Symfony will take SendGrid as his Email server?

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/symfony.html

Comment: @xurshid29 the link you provided is about the integration with sf1 version. Have you tried the suggested configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used composer to just add SendGrid into Symfony:

```
"require": {
"sendgrid/sendgrid": "2.0.5"
```

Then, I added this use:

```
use SendGrid;
```

and finally, just used this code:

```
$sendgrid = new SendGrid("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$email -> addTo("wherever@gmail.com")
-> setFrom("fromever@gmail.com")
-> setSubject("the sub")
-> setHtml("content");

$email_sending_result = $sendgrid -> send($email);
```